# IOS 8.2 Swift Google Sign in button text doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I add Google Sign in button on my Swift app on IOS 8.2.
I followed the google developpers tutorial but my button have not text label on it.

Have you got an idea of this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you have used so we can identify the issue?

Comment: I installed google sdk 2.1 manually.

Comment: You followed the tutorial, I assume there is some code to be written from this? If you supply this with your question I think there will be someone who can spot what is wrong.

Comment: You could find my code [here](https://github.com/ystreibel/SNTCloud)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I solved it.

Try adding `GoogleSignIn.bundle` into your project. Then you can see a TextLabel and Google icon!

Comment: Hi, How did you do this cause I add `GoogleSignIn.bundle` to my IOS project and the Google Sign in button text doesn't appear ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and fix it.

I just clean the project and rebuild it.

Hope this works too for you!

Comment: worked for me today although this didn't work last week

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was working fine on simulator but not on device and the problem was in Pod file, I noticed that while installing pods i was getting this warning - [!] Google has been deprecated

I replace 'pod Google/SignIn' with 'pod GoogleSignIn' and after installing pod, it worked.

It took lots of time to me to figure out this issue. Hope this answer save someone time :)

Comment: I have the same issue but this isnt working for me. I already had `pod GoogleSignIn` and I ran `pod update` just to be sure and still my `googleSignInButton` isn't showing any text

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting: GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide

See: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin#size

```
<GoogleSigninButton
    style={{ width: 200, height: 48 }}
    size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
    onPress={this._signIn}
    disabled={this.state.isSigninInProgress}/>
```

Their example uses ...Size.Icon which has no text.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would design the login with google with Sketch, then use it as background image of this button.